# How to compile C function with __asm and __attribute__ in mbed compiler

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, arm, mbed

I'm trying to compile this rf_lock code([link](https://github.com/ucsb-seclab/pretender/tree/master/test_programs/max32600/rf_lock)) on Mbed online compiler.

Platform is `MAX32600MBED`.

For invoking `startForkserver` aflCall, paste the following snippet to the file in rf_lock, following [this](https://github.com/RiS3-Lab/p2im/blob/master/docs/prep_fw_for_fuzzing.md).

But it seems mbed compiler has a different syntax for inline assembly from GCC, convert `__asm__` to `__asm` and `__volatile__` to `__volatile` and remove `$`,`#`.

```c
// afl_call.h
#include <stdint.h>

__attribute__ ((naked)) uint32_t aflCall(__attribute__ ((unused)) uint32_t a0, __attribute__ ((unused)) uint32_t a1, __attribute__ ((unused)) int32_t a2)
{
    /*
     * In qemu, svc $0x3f is intercepted, without being executed
     * On real device, it is executed and may cause firmware crash
     * It can be skipped by set noHyperCall to 1
     */
    __asm __volatile(
        "svc 0x3f\n\t"
        "bx lr\n\t"
    );
}
```

But warning and error show,

```sh
Warning: Unknown attribute "naked" in "rf_lock/afl_call.c", Line: 5, Col: 18
Error: This instruction not permitted in inline assembler "svc 0x3f\n\t" in "rf_lock/afl_call.c", Line: 13, Col: 11
```

[compiler error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaMNq.png)(image ver.)

I was wondering if anyone could help me.

---

Add

[file organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9I9A.png)

sample code case

```c
// afl_call.h
__attribute__ ((naked)) uint32_t aflCall(__attribute__ ((unused)) uint32_t a0, __attribute__ ((unused)) uint32_t a1, __attribute__ ((unused)) int32_t a2) {
    /*
     * In qemu, svc $0x3f is intercepted, without being executed
     * On real device, it is executed and may cause firmware crash
     * It can be skipped by set noHyperCall to 1
     */
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("svc $0x3f\n\t"
                          "bx %lr\n\t");
}
```

try to compile

```sh
Warning: Unknown attribute "naked" in "rf_lock/afl_call.c", Line: 5, Col: 18
Error: Identifier "$0x3f" is undefined in "rf_lock/afl_call.c", Line: 11, Col: 29
```

[compiler error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffH5P.png)(image ver.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is over average of new users, however, please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. -- As with any other compiler system, I would expect that mbed comes with documentation. What did your research on `__attribute__` and permitted assembly syntax reveal?

Comment: @mmt - It seems the _Mbed online compiler_ is too old - Arm Compiler for Embedded Version 6.17 knows [`__attribute__((naked))`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101754/0617/armclang-Reference/Compiler-specific-Function--Variable--and-Type-Attributes/--attribute----naked---function-attribute).

Comment: @Armali
I try to compile on IDE(Mbed Studio) insted of Mbed Online compiler.
The IDE change the Mbed compiler version.
So I try to compile various versions Mbed compiler.  It maybe mbed-os-5.x .
Thank you